# TFS branch settings

Tags: tfs

I had made some project settings in TFS. When I create a branch of that project I lost all my settings in branch. Is there any way to keep project settings in branch also ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by project settings?  Creating a branch creates an exact copy of all files at the time of the branch.

Comment: Maybe there were some files that weren't checked in. It's hard for the server to branch files it doesn't know about.